# ASP.NET MVC C# Attribute route {somestring}-{somedate:date} not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Stack!

The following attribute route is not working:

```
[Route("{somestring}-{somedate:datetime}")]
public ActionResult SomeMethod(string somestring, DateTime somedate)
```

Example:

```
some-string-01-01-2016
a-name-another-name-02-02-2016
```

Does any anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Use another delimiter?

Comment: I could use another, but I am trying to avoid it for the looks of the url

Comment: This won't work also:
{somestring:alpha}-{data:regex([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})} <- this should work for: something-01-01-2016, but it is not :(

Answer (score 0):

Automatic mapping in MVC working little different then you can expect... It means that ASP will pas to first parameter (from left) as much as can and then the same for next and next...

I can't explain this more because of my 'English' - however read about `*` character in route templates - it's probably what you need.

You can start form official documentation - it's quite good: [ASP.NET Routing](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html)

Also you can try use another delimiter like Danny Chen said or you can try add [Route Constraints](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html#route-constraints) for `somestring` - something like 'non digit'.

Comment: Thanks! I tried many constraints, but I couldnt find a solution. Only by changing the demiliter

Comment: So, maybe solution is using only one parameter with `*` (catch-all). You can pass full string to this one parameter and then you can split them as you want/need inside of action ?

Comment: Also DateTime not always is dd-mm-yyy, it depends form system and often its dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy  or yyyy/mm/dd - maybe thid is problem in yout case ? Tray using string for date time ?